# how do you create a loop that cycles through more than one List in C#

Tags: c#, list, function, loops

I do not want the answer, I would just like how to go about this or some examples please !

**Requirements**

> Create a custom method called CombineTheLists and use the 2 lists you
>   created as arguments in the function call.
>
> i. This method should have 2 parameters and catch the incoming Lists.
>
> ii. It should not return anything.
>
> iii. Inside of the function, create a loop that cycles through both
>   lists at the same time.
>
> iv. Each time the loop runs, pull an item from the 1st List and the
>   matching price from the 2nd List and combine them into one text string
>   using the format of “The X costs $Y.” Where X is the item to be bought
>   and Y is a the cost of the item. Make sure to use a $ and format to 2
>   decimal places

**My Current Code**

```
enter code    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // list for items
        List<string> items = new List<string>() { 
          "laptop", "book", "backpack", "cellphone", "pencils", "notebook", "pens" };

        // list for prices
        List<double> prices = new List<double>() { 
          900.54, 40.20, 21.00, 600.00, 4.25, 10.50, 5.00 };
    }
}   

public static void CombineTheLists( string item, double prices)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
    {

    }
}

}
```

Comment: _I do not want the answer..._ Why do you ask a question then?

Comment: @B001ᛦ most people tend to finish off my code to completion, I simply want their own examples or ideas on how to go about it ... not to give the answer to my specific code.

Comment: Are the two lists always going to have the same number of items?

Comment: @SBFrancies yes they are hard coded, I set the values

Comment: "*It should catch the incoming Lists*" - then `string item, double prices` should be `List<string> item, List<double> prices` in your parameters

Comment: `CombineTheLists` should Combine List as the name, but it doesnt take list as parameter.. `item.Length` will give the lengt of a string not the lenght of the list.

Comment: `CombineTheLists(List<string> items, List<double> prices)` is what you describe.  The int loop inside is correct for that scenario.  Just look at `ElementAt(i);`

Comment: @RoVaLu, I'm pretty sure SbFrancies use a Rhetorical  question. You function should verify that the parameter have the same lenght so it throw no error

Comment: I will either Zip list together or build a dictionary because if one item as a price the link should be stronger than sharing the same index in 2 different list

Comment: You are not far from the solution. Printing `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The {0} costs ${1:.00}", items[i], prices[i]));` inside a `for` or `foreach` loop should do the trick.

Comment: @ValentinP, With for each you have no `i`, If you need to have an `i` declare outside of the foreach using for will be more clear.

Comment: @Drag and Drop, Yes, for sure.

Comment: @DragandDrop These are all just suggestions which is what the OP asked for.  Ideally they wouldn't be 2 lists - it would be 1 list of objects with any number of properties, 2 of which would be the item name and item price.  Using 2 lists is clearly bad for many reasons.

Comment: through doing a bunch of these assignments, I am starting to realize they are not the most functional especially not being allowed to use regex in a lot of the assignments but I guess thats how one learns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that you are looking for `Zip`:

```
var data = items
  .Zip(prices, (item, price) => new {
     item,
     price });

...

foreach (var value in data) {
  // value.item  for item
  // value.price for price
}
```

**Edit:** In case of good old `for` loop:

```
namespace MySolution {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      ...

      CombineTheLists(items, prices);
    }

    public static void CombineTheLists(List<string> items, List<double> prices) {
      for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(items.Count, prices.Count); ++i)
        Console.WriteLine($"item {items[i]} costs {prices[i]:f2}"); // f2 - format string
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I am a student, and we are not allowed to go outside the scope of what we have learned. so far we haven't touched upon .Zip

Comment: any idea why I am getting a syntax error on my method name ? (namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods)

Comment: Im pretty sure your answer was not there when Sweeper post his. Thats 9 minutes. How do you hide answer for that long ?

Comment: @RoVaLu, things need to be in a class.. Namespace> Class> Fiel/method

Comment: @Drag and Drop: I've put answer with `Zip`, got respose that `Zip` was not accepted and provided version with the `for` loop: several edits, and that's why I got 9 min time difference

Comment: Ok you are just fast.

Comment: everything is within a class nothing has changed in class method or function since my initial code

Comment: @DmitryBychenko one last thing, what exactly do I return back to my main method?

Comment: @RoVaLu: `CombineTheLists` returns *nothing* since it's declared as `void`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko  further in my instructions, it states to create a function call in my main method to run my for loop and to output the console.writeline(); doesn't there need to be a return in order to have a function call ?

Comment: @RoVaLu: No. There's no need for `return;` but you can safely add it in the end of the method: `public static void CombineTheLists(...) {for(...) Console.WriteLine(...); return;}`. Since `CombineTheLists` returns *nothing* we have no need to put it explicitly `return;` (which means "please return noithing")

Comment: @RoVaLu:  Function always have a return type. `void` is the return type, it show that the function will return Nothing. So the function does not need a return.

Comment: so how does one create a function call within my main method in this situation ?

Comment: @RoVaLu: `CombineTheLists(items, prices);` - call `CombineTheLists` while passing `items` and `prices` as arguments

Answer (score 2):

You are on (one of) the right tracks, but first, you should change your method declaration to accept two lists, instead of a string and double:

```
public static void CombineTheLists(List<string> items, List<double> prices)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

You already have written a for loop with the looping variable `i`. As you know, `i` will increase every iteration. This means that `items[i]` will be the corresponding item in that iteration and `prices[i]` will be the corresponding price. For example, here's some code to print the item and price on one line:

```
// in the for loop
Console.WriteLine($"{items[i]} - {prices[i]}");
// try to do the formatting to 2 d.p. yourself
```

Comment: Typo: `i < item.Length` should be `i < items.Count`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: @Drag and Drop: *indexer* `[...]` will do with `List<T>` as well; `items[i]` is a correct syntax. You, probably, are mixing C# and Java

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a object with two attributes and a list of objects?

```
 class item {
        String name;
        String price;

        /*getter and setters*/
        }
class main {
     public static void CombineTheLists()
    {
        List<item> items = new List<item>() { item1, item2, item3,.... };
    }
}
```